# Remove a child menu item

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, menu

I have a asp menu as show below. I want to hide the sub item having text "Old" from code behind in one of the case.

```
<asp:Menu ID="Viewmenu" runat="server" Visible="true" PathSeparator=","   BackColor="#FFFFEB" DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" >

  <Items>
      <asp:MenuItem Text="View" Value="New Item">
              <asp:MenuItem Text="Old" Value="Old que"></asp:MenuItem> 
              <asp:MenuItem Text="Profile" Value="Address"></asp:MenuItem>
      </asp:MenuItem>
  </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

So i used [finditem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.finditem(v=vs.110).aspx) and then item remove from code behind as shown below

```
Dim s As MenuItem
s = Viewmenu.FindItem("New Item,Old que")
Viewmenu.Items.Remove(s)
```

But above code run without any error, but the menu item having Text="Old"  is not removed and is shown in menu.(in my case I am trying to remove a sub menuitem from a menuitem)
I tried using `Viewmenu.FindItem("New Item")` just to check whether code works and complete menu itself removed as expected.

So why does remove a menu item inside a menuitem didn't work? What I am missing? OR is there any better way to achieve the same from code behind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code,hope it helps,and you used C# tag,but I guess your code is VB

C# Code

```
MenuItem parent = Viewmenu.FindItem("New Item"); 
MenuItem s = Viewmenu.FindItem("@New Item\Old que");
parent.ChildItems.Remove(s);
```

VB Code

```
Dim parent As MenuItem = Viewmenu.FindItem("New Item")
Dim s As MenuItem = Viewmenu.FindItem("New Item,Old que")
parent.ChildItems.Remove(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

The VB Code that worked for me was:

```
Dim parent As MenuItem = Viewmenu.FindItem("New Item")
Dim s As MenuItem = Viewmenu.FindItem("New Item/Old que")
parent.ChildItems.Remove(s)
```

Note the forward slash on the second line.